# How to save new created folder based name of person defined in integer

Tags: excel, vba

I have created folder by user name which defined in "V"

```
MkDir ("D:\Test\" & V)
```

Now I want save file in respective folder name:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "D:\Test\" & V & "_" & Format(Date, "dd-mmm-yyyy") & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=51
```

Is this code right?

Comment: Well, did you run your own code and examined the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with a backslash included:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "D:\Test" & V & "\" & Format(Date, "dd-mmm-yyyy") & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=51
```